# Java AES CTR mode decryption given a key, ciphertext, and plaintext

Tags: java, encryption

Alright, so my problem is that I want to decrypt E(K, IV) to get the IV. I know the key, ciphertexts C1 and C2, plaintext C1 (corresponding to P2) and I want to find plaintext P2. I first did C1 ^ P1 to get E(K, IV). Now I want to invert E(K, IV) using the key to get IV so that I can decrypt P2. But, I cannot figure out how to do this in Java. Here is my code for that so far:

```
    byte[] temp = plainText1;
    int i = 0;
    for (byte b : plainText1) {
        temp[i] =  (byte) (b ^ cipherText1[i++]);
    }
    //Results in a 69 byte message, so I need to take only 16 of it.
    byte[] block = Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, 0, 16);
    byte[] key; //Assume this is known, 16 bytes
    //decrypt E(K, T) to get IV
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] initVector = c.doFinal(block);
```

The problem is the decrypting part. It gives me a BadPaddingException even though there is no padding involved. How should I do this to get the IV?

Comment: Usually the IV is just prepended to the ciphertext (iv|ciphertext) so the first 16 bytes (for AES) are the iv. But what is the usage of the iv? Your decryption instantiation is just "AES" and that means "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" as default - for this reason you receive the "BadPaddingException". I do not see any CTR mode used for decryption? It could be good idea to show the encryption part to be for shure what mode is in use and how the iv is used. Your key as well is just an empty byte[], so there's too much room for arguing.

Comment: You could use `AES/ECB/NoPadding` to decrypt a _complete_ block (inverse of _E(K, IV)_). But even if you have the IV of the first encryption, how does that help with the second one, since the IVs are generally generated randomly for each encryption (but maybe I misunderstand the scenario).

Comment: @Michael Fehr CTR requires an IV to decrypt since P2 = C2 ^ E(K, IV), so I cant use it. The key is not empty, it has 16 bytes but I just did not want to put it there.

Comment: Even if the numbers 1 and 2 denote the block, you must also set the index on the IV: _P2 = C2 XOR E(K, IV2)_.

Comment: @Topaco CTR works by storing a counter along with the IV for the subsequent blocks and then encrypting that with the key. Fortunately I know the counter (it is +1 per block), so if I can get the IV I can consequently decrypt the remaining blocks.

Comment: In your formula IV denotes a concatenated nonce and counter, i.e. for the 2nd block the incremented IV must be used. Moreover, _E(K,IV1) = C1 XOR P1_ should be decryptable with `AES/ECB/NoPadding`, because _E(K,IV1)_ is a common AES encryption of _IV1_.